# zod localisation of messages for err

Tags: node.js, internationalization, zod

As everyone is aware the npm package zod is awesome for validation/parsing.
It would be great if the error messages can be translated to another language as english?
Did anyone try to use localisation on ZOD?

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/aiji42/zod-i18n?

Comment: Sadly that package only works with i18next not with other translation libs like lingui.